# Expected value of a product of random variable

Tags: probability

If  I have two zero mean random variables say $x$ and $y$, and there is a function $f$ such that 
$$\mathrm{Var}(x+f(x)) \approx \mathrm{Var}(x)$$ and 
$$\mathrm{Var}(y+f(y)) \approx \mathrm{Var}(y)\; .$$

If we constrain $f$ such that $$E{f(x)}=E{f(y)}=0$$ and $x > f(x)$, for all $x$,
Can I say that

$$E[(x+f(x))\cdot(y+f(y))] \approx E(xy) \; ?$$

Comment: If $X$ is a zero mean random variable and $X > f(X)$, why we still have $\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = 0$? (It is supposed to be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation.)

Comment: Unless you provide the precise and mathematical meaning of the symbol $\approx$, it seems difficult to understand your question, let alone to answer it.

Comment: @Hsueh-Yung Lin Even if $x$ is a zero mean random variable, and $x>f(x)$, both can be zero mean. Consider f() as a ladder function (generally used in quantization of a scalar variable).

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Dear user12268, I can't agree with you. Compose a function by $\mathbb{E}$ is like integrate a such function. In our case, $X>f(X)$ "everywhere", so $\mathbb{E}[X] > \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$.